# Mysql CASE with multiple substring legths

Tags: mysql, sql

I have hundreds of phone number of the world. Each has its country prefix (the prefix varies: some are 1, 2, 3 or 4 digit long) + the phone number. I want to write a mysql query, which will show me the Country name by using the prefix.

Example : If i use sub-string for the first 3 digits, its working fine. But how i can show the prefixes which are 2 or 4 digit long ?

```
SELECT(
CASE (SUBSTR(Number,1,3))
WHEN '998' Then 'Uzbekistan '
WHEN '996' Then 'Kyrgyzstan '
WHEN '995' Then 'Georgia '
.....
....
ELSE 'OTHERS' END ) AS Country
```

Comment: post some data example for better clarity

Comment: It might be helpful if country code is its own field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is based on the fact that the `CASE` statement is evaluated sequentially.

```
SELECT(
    CASE 
      WHEN SUBSTR(Number,1,2) = '23' Then 'Try For 23 '   
      WHEN SUBSTR(Number,1,3) = '998' Then 'Uzbekistan '
      WHEN SUBSTR(Number,1,3) = '996' Then 'Kyrgyzstan '
      WHEN SUBSTR(Number,1,3) = '995' Then 'Georgia '
     .....
     ....
     ELSE 'OTHERS' END ) AS Country
```

Comment: Is their any way that i can combine the prefixes which has 3 digits. Something like ---- WHEN SUBSTR(Number,1,3) = '998' Then 'Uzbekistan ' OR '996' Then 'Kyrgyzstan ' OR '995' Then 'Georgia '

Comment: @Ayaz    No using OR like in you comment  is not possibile .. could be using nested  case when  but seems too complex ..(at least  for me)

Comment: You can use nested CASE statements: CASE SUBSTR(Number,1,2) WHEN '33' THEN 'France' WHEN '39' THEN 'Italy' ELSE (CASE SUBSTR(Number,1,3) WHEN '998' THEN 'Uzbekistan ' WHEN '996' THEN 'Kyrgyzstan' END) END